# moment isBetween returning false

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to evaluate this instruction

```
moment('06:17:20+00:00').isBetween('06:16:20+00:00', '06:19:20+00:00');
```

For me, it should return `true` but it's not the case. I'm getting `false`

I read documentation but still not understand why i'm getting false

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/custo5r6/1/)

Here's a snippet

```js
const out = document.getElementById('output');

const test = moment('06:17:20+00:00').isBetween('06:16:20+00:00', '06:19:20+00:00');
out.innerText = test;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: `06:17:20+00:00` is an invalid date and you are getting a warning about it. How about following the mentioned instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<p id="output"></p>
```

**JS**

```
const out = document.getElementById('output');
var format = 'hh:mm:ss',
beforeTime = moment('06:16:20+00:00', format),
afterTime = moment('06:19:20+00:00', format);

const test = moment('06:17:20+00:00',format).isBetween(beforeTime, afterTime);
out.innerText = test;
```

working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cruz888/54ye9swk/4/

Answer (score 2):

Formating value can help :

```
moment('2019-06-12T06:17:20').isBetween('2019-06-12T06:16:20', '2019-06-12T06:19:20');
```

Comment: is it possible to convert date format that I provide to your format automatocally ?

Comment: Yes sure You need to add the date to your format and you can convert using `replace()` for example